# extract integers from characters in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data-transform

I am in R. I want to extract just the numbers from df1.
I have for example:
 `df1 <- data.frame( column1 = c("Any[12, 15, 20]", "Any[22, 23, 30]"), column2 = c("Any[4, 17]", "Any[]"), stringsAsFactors = F )`

And I want a new df, that takes the integers within the brackets muliples by the row number, and keeps the column information corresponding to it.

e.g.
new_df could look like

| Time | Channel |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | column1 |
| 15 | column1 |
| 20 | column1 |
| 44 | column1 |
| 46 | column1 |
| 60 | column1 |
| 8 | column2 |
| 34 | column2 |

I do not need to preserve any "NA" values, e.g If Any[] is empty.
Anyone got any idea if this is possible please?
I have ENORMOUS amounts of data in this format, so I cannot really do much manually.
Cheers!

I already tried:
`new_df$Time <- as.integer(df1$column1)`
and that just gave blanks.

I also tried:
`new_df$Time <- str_extract_all(new_df$Time, "\\d+" ) %>% lapply(function(x) as.integer(x)) %>% sapply(function(x) if.else(length(x) >0, x, NA) )`

which only then returned the first integer within each bracket.
e.g.

| Time | Channel |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | column1 |
| 44 | column1 |
| 8 | column2 |

Comment: Thank you so much for your help everyone!! I really appreciated the help, and the guidance of how these solutions work. Using purrr and imap worked super nicely in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df1|>
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) imap(str_extract_all(x, "\\d+"), ~ as.numeric(.x) * .y))) |>
  pivot_longer(everything(), cols_vary = "slowest", names_to = "Time", values_to = "Channel") |>
  unnest_longer(Channel)
```

**How it works**

This is similar to the approach you took in your initial attempt except I am using `purrr::imap` instead of `lapply`. The advantage here is that `imap` gives you access to the list element name (`.y`), which is the row number in this case, in addition to the list element (`.x`). This makes the multiple multiplication step simple.

`str_extract_all` extracts all the numbers from a column and outputs those numbers in a list:

```r
str_extract_all(df1$column1, "\\d+")
[[1]]
[1] "12" "15" "20"

[[2]]
[1] "22" "23" "30"
```

`imap` iterates over this list and does the multiplication:

```r
imap(str_extract_all(df1$column1, "\\d+"), ~ as.numeric(.x) * .y)
[[1]]
[1] 12 15 20

[[2]]
[1] 44 46 60
```

Then the other two pipes are to reshape the data.

**Output**

```r
  Time    Channel
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 column1      12
2 column1      15
3 column1      20
4 column1      44
5 column1      46
6 column1      60
7 column2       4
8 column2      17
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work. Note that `parse_number` will issue a warning for rows with no numbers. You could wrap it in `suppressWanings()` to silence it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
df1 |>
  mutate(rn = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-rn, names_to = "channel", values_to = "time") |>
  separate_longer_delim(time, delim = ",") |>
  mutate(time = parse_number(time) * rn) |>
  arrange(channel, rn) |>
  select(-rn) |>
  filter(!is.na(time))
# # A tibble: 8 × 2
#   channel  time
#   <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 column1    12
# 2 column1    15
# 3 column1    20
# 4 column1    44
# 5 column1    46
# 6 column1    60
# 7 column2     4
# 8 column2    17
# Warning message:
# There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
# ℹ In argument: `time = parse_number(time)`.
# Caused by warning:
# ! 1 parsing failure.
# row col expected actual
#   9  -- a number  Any[]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution. First create a list of values. This regex either retrieves the numbers and commas within `"Any[]"`, or it replaces an empty `"Any[]"` with a blank string.

```r
df_values <- lapply(df1, \(col) gsub("Any\\[(.+)\\]|Any\\[\\]", "\\1", col))
```

We can then iterate over that list and its names using [`Map()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) to get the data in the format that you need, and multiply by the row number.

```r
df_long <- Map(\(x, nm) {
    time <- strsplit(x, ",") |>
        lapply(\(x) as.integer(trimws(x)))

    # Multiply by row number
    time_mult <- unlist(time) * rep(seq(lengths(time)), lengths(time))

    data.frame(
        Time = time_mult,
        Channel = nm
    )
}, df_values, names(df_values)) |>
    do.call(rbind, args = _)

print(df_long, row.names = FALSE)

#  Time Channel
#    12 column1
#    15 column1
#    20 column1
#    44 column1
#    46 column1
#    60 column1
#     4 column2
#    17 column2
```

Answer (score 3):

Another base R solution:

```
extract_ints <- function(df) {
  extract_cell_ints <- function(x, multiplier) {
    as.integer(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[0-9]+", x))[[1L]]) * multiplier
  }
  raw_ints <- lapply(
    df1,
    # Using row number as multiplier
    \(cl) Map(extract_cell_ints, x = cl, multiplier = seq_along(cl))
  )
  data.frame(
    Time    = unlist(raw_ints, use.names = FALSE), 
    Channel = rep(names(df), sapply(raw_ints, \(x) sum(lengths(x))))
  )
}

 
extract_ints(df1)

#   Time Channel
# 1   12 column1
# 2   15 column1
# 3   20 column1
# 4   44 column1
# 5   46 column1
# 6   60 column1
# 7    4 column2
# 8   17 column2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following base R solution, using `str2lang` + `stack`

```
setNames(
    stack(
        lapply(
            df1,
            \(s) eval(str2lang(sprintf(
                "c(%s)",
                toString(paste0(seq_along(s), "*", gsub("Any\\[(.*?)\\]", "c(\\1)", s)))
            )))
        )
    ),
    c("Time", "Channel")
)
```

which gives

```
  Time Channel
1   12 column1
2   15 column1
3   20 column1
4   44 column1
5   46 column1
6   60 column1
7    4 column2
8   17 column2
```